# Apache FOP external graphics auto height to fit the page

Tags: pdf, scale, apache-fop

I have a scenario in which I'm embedding an image in pdf using `fo:external graphic`. However the image size is dynamic and I have to fit it in single page. I'm scaling down the image both horizontal and vertical by maintaining the aspect ratio as below.

```
<fo:block text-align="left" margin-top="10" 
        height="22cm" width="18cm">
    <fo:external-graphic height="100%" width="100%" 
            content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit" 
            scaling="uniform" >
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:text>url('data:image/png</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>;base64,</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="BASE_64_IMAGE"/>
            <xsl:text>')</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </fo:external-graphic>
</fo:block>
```

This works fine for large vertical images. But once scaled down, if the image is small in size vertically, text content is not populated below the image. Instead it will be populated in next page. But I want the text to appear just below the image if image is small.

Can someone please help me to solve this?

Comment: Which version of FOP are you using?

Comment: I'm using fop 2.1